# R markdown results='hold' but for messages?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have functions outputting multiple messages in my code and I can't get these messages to be in the same output chunk, like with `results='hold'`.

As of now, the only option that kind of emulates what I want is the `collapse=T` option, but this sticks the output and the code together, which I don't want.

This code illustrates the situation :

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "Me"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```



```{r}
a <- function(){
  print("hello")
  print("world")
  message("hello again")
  message("world")
}
```

### default
```{r}
a()
```


### with `results='hold'`
```{r results='hold'}
a()
```


### with `collapse=T`
```{r collapse=T}
a()
```
````

Output :
[image: rmd]

I also think It's interesting how the messages get outputted before the results/prints with `results='hold'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different version that may fit better with what OP wanted.

This version will mingle the messages and output together as they would be observed had they been sent to the console.

This is done by overriding three hooks: `message`, `output`, and `chunk`.

## Contents of Rmd

````
---
title: "Knitr As Console Output Hook Implementation"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

# global store for output and messages
asconsole_output <- NULL

# override message hook
# if output option is 'asconsole', append message to global
# otherwise let knitr do its thing
knitr::knit_hooks$set(message = function(x, options) {
  if(!is.null(options$output)) {
    if(options$output == 'asconsole') {
      asconsole_output <<- c(asconsole_output, x)
      return(NULL)
    }
  }
  
  knitr::hooks_html()$message(x, options)
})
  
# override output hook
# if output option is 'asconsole', append output to global
# otherwise let knitr do its thing
knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  if(!is.null(options$output)) {
    if(options$output == 'asconsole') {
      asconsole_output <<- c(asconsole_output, x)
      return(NULL)
    }
  }
  
  knitr::hooks_html()$output(x, options)
})

# override chunk hook
# if output option is 'asconsole', clear global and append formatted contents
# otherwise let knitr do its thing
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  if(!is.null(options$output)) {
    if(options$output == 'asconsole') {
      y <- paste(asconsole_output, collapse = "")
      y <- knitr::hooks_html()$output(y, options)
      asconsole_output <<- NULL
      y <- paste(x, y, collapse = "")
      return(y)
    }
  }
  
  knitr::hooks_html()$chunk(x, options)
})

# test function with results and messages
a <- function() {
  print("a out 1")
  message("a msg 1")
  print("a out 2")
  message("a msg 2")
}
```

# Default Behavior

```{r}
a()
```

# Output As Console

```{r, output='asconsole'}
a()
```
````

## Output HTML

[image]

Comment: I will accept this answer since it adresses my initial question, even if people may be more interested in your other answer (that got the bounty)

Answer (score 2):

An option to hold messages similar to how results are holdable, can be implemented by overriding the default knitr output hooks `message` and `chunk`.

This approach still allows results to be held should one wish to collate results that would otherwise be split by the occurrence of a message.

## Contents of Rmd

````
---
title: "Knitr Message Hold Hook Implementation"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

# global store for current chunk messages
current_messages <- NULL

# override default message hook
# if message option is hold, copy messages to the global store and print nothing
# otherwise let knitr do its thing
knitr::knit_hooks$set(message = function(x, options) {
  if (options$message == "hold") {
    current_messages <<- c(current_messages, x)
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    return(knitr::hooks_html()$message(x, options))
  }
})

# override chunk hook
# if message option is hold, clear global store, and append prepared messages
# otherwise let knitr do its thing
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  if (options$message == "hold") {
    collapsed_messages <- paste(current_messages, collapse = "")
    options$message <- TRUE
    messages <- knitr::hooks_html()$message(collapsed_messages, options)
    current_messages <<- NULL
    paste(x, messages, collapse = "")
  } else {
    knitr::hooks_html()$chunk(x, options)
  }
})

# test function with results and messages
a <- function() {
  print("a out 1")
  message("a msg 1")
  print("a out 2")
  message("a msg 2")
}
```

# Default Behavior

```{r}
a()
```

# Holding Messages

```{r, message='hold'}
a()
```

# Holding Results

```{r, results='hold'}
a()
```

# Holding Messages and Results

```{r, message='hold', results='hold'}
a()
```
````

## Output HTML

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve it quite elegantly with the superassignment of messages. Do you happen to know the place in knitr source where this default message markup is written? I'm curious about this `class = "hljs"` piece.

Comment: I do not know as I got that markup by inspecting a knitted html document with default settings. I suspect it has to do with [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

Comment: It's been a while since I asked the question, but this is a pretty nice solution. Is there a way to get all the outputs in a single block? What would happen if there is a print, then a message, then another print ? I initially wanted an output similar to what I'd get from console output (*i.e.* in the order the msg/print is executed)

Comment: I have updated the answer to a more elegant solution that allows one to rely on the existing hold results option.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any solution using chunks option [docs1](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) [docs2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html#r-code)

The only thing that comes to my mind is to have two chunks - one for displaying the code without evaluation and second one collapsing outputs but without code:

````
### Two blocs
```{r eval=FALSE}
a()
```
```{r collapse=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
a()
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty good approach for those wanting a quick fix without too much trouble. However, it makes it annoying to update code blocks, as you will need to do everything twice!